# Does a subspace of a finite dimensional vector space has a unique complement

Tags: vector-spaces

Question-

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space and let $W$ is a subspace of $V$. Then prove that $W$
has unique complement if and only if $W$ = {0} or $W$ = $V$.

I have tried solving the question in many ways but I am not able to approach the problem maybe correctly, and hence not able to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Let $\{0\} \subsetneq W \subseteq V$, $\{e_1, \dots, e_n\}$ be a basis of $V$ where $\{e_1, \dots, e_m\}$ ($1 \le m <n$) is a basis of $W$.

Then the linear subspaces $A,B$ generated respectively by $\{e_{m+1}, \dots, e_n\}$ and $\{e_{m+1}+e_1, \dots, e_n+e_1\}$ are different though both complement of $W$.